# JAVA 2 classes GUI set text

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a problem with my java UI. So i made my code for adding numbers that works in console but i wanted to port it fully to GUI. I made GUI(second file class named NewJFrame.java) in the netbeans GUI editor, i've set a label and a text field in it. Then I tried to make the output come out in the Label and let the user put input inside the textfield. I found out that i cannot change the text of the label with .setText because the code generated in NetBeans is private. Is there any way i can try to do it differently? Here's the current code i've got and thanks in advance for all the answers!

```
 package pkg1addition;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = 0;

    while (true) {

        if (input.hasNext("[0-9]+")) {
            number1 = input.nextInt();
            break;
        } else {
             NewJFrame.outputField.setText("something something");
            //System.out.print("Not a number, try again. ");
            input.next();
        }

    }

    System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");

    int number2 = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (input.hasNext("[0-9]+")) {
            number2 = input.nextInt();
            break;
        } else {
             NewJFrame.outputField.setText("something something");
            //System.out.println("Not a number, try again. ");
            input.next();
        }

    }
    int sum = number1 + number2;
    NewJFrame.outputField.setText("something something");
    //System.out.printf("Your sum is: %d%n", sum);

}
}
```

Comment: you could write a get/set method to help with setting your text on the jlabel

Comment: would you mind explaining in more detail? my jlabel's name is outputField so should i try it like public void setOutputfield ( String n ) {
   Outputfield = n;
}

Comment: pretty much -- `public void setLabel( String str){ outputfield.setText(str); }`

Comment: You are still trying to read the values from console (so if you don't enter anything nothing will happen). To also port the input to the GUI you have to `setFocus` on the text field and make it commit when the user clicks on a button or pushes enter (listeners) and then you set the content in the label, clear the text field and set the focus again.